# How to build search page with PHP and Yii2?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, activerecord, yii2

I need to build a search page with PHP (preferably using Yii2 framework) similar to [this one](http://www.bipsolutions.com/cpvtool/bip-cpv-search-tool.html).

Let me explain this further. There are 6 levels of "CPV codes". Users will see the first level as links all the time, and there are 45 of them. When user click on some first level CPV code, for example **CPV 24000000 - Chemical products**, they will see 7 new links, CPV codes of second level.

At that moment I want to give users 2 buttons next to each link from second level cpv code, one for up, second for down, meaning that if they click up, they will see CPV code that is one level higher, in this case they will be back to 24000000, or if they click on some CPV of second level (down) they will see CPV codes of third level, but related to the one they chose from second.

So if first level is **24000000**, once they click on it they will see 7 CPV codes of second level like this:

```
 24100000 : Gases  
 24200000 : Dyes and pigments  
 24300000 : Basic inorganic and organic chemicals  
 24400000 : Fertilisers and nitrogen compounds  
 24500000 : Plastics in primary forms  
 24600000 : Explosives  
 24900000 : Fine and various chemical products
```

At this moment, next to each of these links there will be 2 options, up and down. If they click **UP** next to **24100000 Gases**, they will see **24000000 Chemical products**, if they click **DOWN**, they will see 
**24110000 : Industrial gases**

If I am storing CPV codes in mysql database table called CPV, and I have 2 columns id = CPV code, and name = CPV name, how can I build this? I have no clue. I know that there is strict hierarchy, but do not know exactly how to use it.

Note: when I pull CPV codes from database, I would like to get it as an array of objects (like Yii2 `findAll()` AR method).

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: It looks like your data is stored in a hierarchy. Have you looked at the "nested set" algorithm? I don't know if the Yii AR library supports that out of the box - if not you could build it yourself, or switch to an ORM that does (e.g. Propel). Other than that, this is rather a broad question as there are a good number of ways in which this could be designed and implemented.

Comment: There [are some promising-looking results here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=nested+set+yii).

Comment: Thanks you for your answers. I have never heard before for nested sets. This https://github.com/creocoder/yii2-nested-sets extension looks promising, but I am not yet sure how I can use this to build what I need.

Comment: Well, I would suggest you start with experimenting with any examples provided by those extensions, and seeing if you can get a proof of concept working (just on the console for now). The simplest demo would be to get one item to be the parent of another. It sounds like you'll need AJAX for this project as well, but one step at a time. Get your database structure and your hierarchy working first.

Comment: The nested sets extension is what you need. I already use it in my project and it works fine.